# Hide rows using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code for a button that shows and hides a table and it seems to work, until the table is populated at which point it will only hide the rows containing no text

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
If CommandButton1.Caption = "Hide" Then
   Dim c As Range
   For Each c In Range("B5:b14")
      If c.Value = "" Then c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
   Next c
   CommandButton1.Caption = "Show"
   
ElseIf CommandButton1.Caption = "Show" Then
   Rows("5:74").EntireRow.Hidden = False
   CommandButton1.Caption = "Hide"
End If
End Sub
```

I imagine it's something to do with the If c.Value = "" section but for the life of me my brain is blank and I can't figure out what

Comment: So if you want all rows to be hidden, why are you testing for empty values??

Comment: And why are you checking only rows 5 to 14 when hiding but rows 5 to 74 when showing the data?

Comment: @Paul - I hadn't populated the table yet when I did the original testing (this is for a uni project so had no data for it yet) - however after populating the table it didn't work.

Comment: The 5:14 vs 5:74 was just an oversight on my part, it should be 5 to 14 for both, have just changed

Comment: `If c.Value = "" Then` means: a row is only hidden if the cell in column B is empty

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide an entire table, you can do so using the range of a `ListObject`.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim isHidden As Boolean
    isHidden  = ToggleTableVisbility(Sheet1.ListObjects(1))
    CommandButton1.Caption = Iif(isHidden, "Show", "Hide")
End Sub

Private Function ToggleTableVisbility(tbl As ListObject) As Boolean
    With tbl.Range
        .Hidden = Not .Hidden
        ToggleTableVisbility = .Hidden
    End With
End Sub
```